# Does Apple's API allow for media controls in the WidgetView?

Tags: ios

Does Apple's media API allow for controls to be implemented in the WidgetView, or would this require private libraries that will get rejected in the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

Apple put Media Controls directly into Mission Control, so I don't think they'd smile on them being integrated into a Widget.